# I want to return the sum of all indexes in n via recursion. How do I do this?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def final_sum(n):
    n = str(n)
    if int(n) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        x = int(n[0])
        return x + int(final_sum(n[1:]))


print(final_sum(123))
```

For example, if my n is 123, I should be getting 6. But I am having an error in this code. Can anyone help? I have to use recursive function. So tell me what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `return x + int(final_sum(n[1:]))`, `n[1:]` is `str` type
in the beginning of the function, with `n = str(n)`, you assume the input is an `int`
Besides, you did not consider the case that `n[1:]` can be empty in `return x + int(final_sum(n[1:]))`.
Here is an anwser based on your code

```py
def final_sum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    n = str(n)
    x = int(n[0])
    if len(n)==1:
        return x
    else:
        return x + final_sum(int(n[1:]))
```

Here is another version using `%` operation

```py
def final_sum(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return n % 10 + final_sum(n // 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the beggining I would do this instead of casting back and forth:

```
def final_sum(n):
    if n<10:
       return n
```

You see, the problem is, in the last recursive iteration, you are passing this to the function:

```
final_sum("")
```

When you should be passing an int. I think this is happening because your last cast is backwards and you never check how many digits the number has. So the code should look like this:

```
def final_sum(n):
    if n<10:
       return n
    n = str(n)
    x = int(n[0])
    return x + final_sum(int(n[1:]))
    
print(final_sum(123))
```